# Difference between getMap() and getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `getMapAsync()` instead of `getMap()` in mapview.But, I wish to know the difference between `getMap()` and `getMapAsync`.

Comment: I think you should need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean this link

Comment: you can't read? Like, documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`getMap() is deprecated`**

> [**`public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))
>
> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap instance is ready to be used.

Note that:

- This method must be called from the main thread.
- The callback will be executed in the main thread.
- In the case where Google Play services is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be triggered until the user installs it.
- In the rare case where the GoogleMap is destroyed immediately after creation, the callback is not triggered.
- The GoogleMap object provided by the callback is non-null.

Answer (score 2):

So, getMapAsync should be used as it waits till the map is properly initialized and provides the Map instance via a callback.

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Place your logic here
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getMapAsync let you use a callback when the map is init ;)